# SSIS connection manager 2012

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I created a package using SSIS 2012; I used a connection manager but that connection manager is setup at Package level using “Convert to Package level  Connection”. 
Now when I run this package using SQL data tool or New 2012 BIDS it runs fine, but when I run package using execute package utility it does not run because it cannot find the Package level connection manager. 
Can you help with this?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://www.mattmasson.com/index.php/2012/07/can-i-deploy-a-single-ssis-package-from-my-project-to-the-ssis-catalog/

Answer (score 0):

It works when you deploy the Project to SSMS. When it deploys, also carries over the connections.